# Access getters with some 'magic method'

Tags: php, design-patterns

I've been reading some things about magic methods lately and the `__call`, `__get` etc.
But I'm not sure which one to use to answer my question.

The situation is as follows:

I got a class `Filter` where I have a `getParams()` method.
How would I be able to grab this method while calling `$filter->params`?

Answer (score 0):

Well did you try it?
You would use the `__get` magic function.

For example

```
class Filter {

    private $params = 'my value';
    public function getParams(){
       return $this->params;
    }
    public function __get($param){
        $method = 'get' . $param;
        return $this->$method();
    }
}


var_dump((new Filter())->params);
```

But I would advise calling the get function directly.

Comment: Why would I use the get function directly? Something for security reasons?